# Best method to store supplemental files in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I need a way to store supplemental files that refer to an instance of an entity in my database. I have a script table and for each script there may be supplemental files (word documents or PDFs) that correspond to that script. I've looked into using a filetable but from what I've read it didn't seem like there was anyway to add a foreign key to the filetable that would refer to the scripts table. I'm not very experienced with SQL so I've never really had to do anything like this and I was just wondering if there's a best method to go about storing those supplemental files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Principal advantage of FileTables is the ability to access the files stored in them through the Windows file system, just like you do with files stored anywhere else. If you don't need this ability, you don't need FileTables and can revert to standard FILESTREAM.

Here is a good starting point: [FILESTREAM (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx)